# Original description of point sources and point spread functions

Tags: mathematics, physics, astronomy

I already asked this question in the [Astronomy community](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/53198/33630), but there it was recommended to me to also try my luck here.

I would like to know the original description of point sources and point spread functions. They are well-known concepts (in particular in astronomy e.g.), but every source that I could find so far that discusses them doesn't mention who actually discovered or came up with them.

The closest thing that I found for now is the work by [Airy](https://archive.org/details/transactionsofca05camb/page/n305/mode/2up), who mathematically described the diffraction pattern generated by a perfect optical system. So I guess that is very close. However, according to the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk), the phenomenon was described by Herschel at least seven years prior. But that is just regarding the outer rings of the diffraction pattern. So I would guess astronomers must have been aware of the blob-like appearance of poin sources even earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer to get things started.

Point sources were a natural concept for mathematicians pondering waves, and the Huygens construction for a spherical wavefront generated by a point source is an expanding spherical shell with each point on the surface being a new point source.

[image: Huygens construction for a spherical wavefront generated by a point source]

Image source: The Fact Factor's [Application of Huygens Wave Theory of Light](https://thefactfactor.com/facts/pure_science/physics/applications-of-huygens-wave-theory-of-light/7673/) but probably cropped from somewhere else.

But I wonder if you are really interested in the development of theory not of point sources, *but of apertures*. [Apodization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apodization) and [point spread function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) go hand-in-hand; in a well-focused and diffraction-limited optical system for example, they are essentially Fourier transforms of each other.

In modern times we apodize all kinds of things, outside of optics as well, cf. [Is it "common practice in Fourier transform spectroscopy to multiply the measured interferogram by an apodizing function"? If so, why?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/111982/16035) in Chemistry SE.

In advanced optical systems pushing limits of resolution like [deep-UV optical photolithography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photolithography#Resolution_in_projection_systems) scanners, the pupil of the lenses can be fitted with both amplitude and phase apodization (as can the illumination systems for the mask)

**All of this taken together** suggests to me that the history of [Fourier optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_optics) may yield some helpful resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very interesting and a great start.